# Instance variable is not returned are this param's considered private

Tags: javascript, closures

Regarding **private variable encapsulation** - achieved by defining the private variable as `var` instead of it being a property of `this` ( not private this.private ). This is the most direct way of making a member private.

But, the above rule makes sense if the instance is being returned and used. In case we return a new object with get/set methods being exposed. Now, does storing the private variable in the `this` param still achieve **private variable encapsulation**

Is there any way that I can get access to the instance param when it's not being returned?

```
function X(init) {
  this.private = init; 
  var that = this
  function get() {
    return that.private;
  }

  function set (tmp) {
    that.private = tmp;
  }

  return {
    get: get,
    set: set
  }
}

var tmp = new X(1);

console.log(tmp.get()) // 1

console.log(tmp instanceof X) // false

tmp.private = 20 // doesnt work as tmp isnt an instance object

console.log(x.get()) //1

x.set(20)

console.log(x.get()) //20
```

Do I have access to **private** as it's a property of `this` when the `this` isnt being returned?

Comment: "a param of this". A parameter is an argument to a function. What you want to say is property.

Comment: your function returns an **object** yet you use it as a constructor.

Comment: @StefanOctavian updated.

Comment: @Wreigh just an example code.

Comment: downvoter?, how is this a bad question?, I genuinely did not know whether I could access the this parameter!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, we can not have access to **private** property on *this* as you are explicitly returning new object.

Comment: My thought exactly. Wanted to make sure that there's no way to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this example when using a constructor:

```
function X()
{
   // Scope of X()
   var i = 1; // this variable is accessible only in this scope
   this.get = function() { return i; };
}

a = new X(); // call the constructor
console.log(a.i); // this will be undefined
a.i = 2; // even if you try to set `i` on `a`

console.log(a.get()); // the actual `i` of `a` will still be 1
console.log(a.i); // this will be two.
```

Now for the example which uses a function which returns an object.

```
function Y()
{
    // Scope of Y()
    var i = 1; // this variable is accessible only in this scope
    function get() { return i; };

    return { // now you return an object which exposes a function that returns the value of `i` of this SCOPE.
        get: get
    }
}

b = Y();

console.log(b.i); // this will be undefined
console.log(b.get()); // this will be 1
b.i = 3; // this will work
console.log(b.get()); // this will still be 1
console.log(b.i); // this will be 3
```

I'm sorry I don't have enough time to continue the explanation, I'll return to this later.

You can hide(make private) *member* variables by hiding it in the scope.

Also, between these two approaches, only the first approach where you will be able to make use of the `this` keyword. You can't use `this` keyword in the second approach as its value will be the **Window**

Comment: my question is, when `{get: get}` is returned - do I have access to the instance ( `this` ) variable ?.

Comment: none of what u've stated seems to answer that. Plz check the given example.

Comment: no you do not have, because you returned a **completely** new object, even if you have used `new`. read my latest update, `this` is only available if you had used `new` keyword in creating the object. in your case, yeah you've used the `new` keyword but you've returned a different object.

Answer (score -2):

You can achieve true privacy using a WeakMap.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/WeakMap

WeakMaps allow you to create an affiliated object on which you can append any values.
You can't access them if you can't access the scope in which they were defined.

Using ES5 in a browser

```
"use strict";
{
    const privacy = new WeakMap();

    function X(init)
    {
        privacy.set(this, {});

        const props = privacy.get(this);

        props.init = init;
    }

    X.prototype.setInit = function(tmp)
    {
        privacy.get(this).init = tmp;
    };

    X.prototype.getInit = function()
    {
        return privacy.get(this).init;
    };

    window.X = X;
}
```

Using ES6 class notation in NodeJS

```
const privacy = new WeakMap();

class X
{
    constructor(init)
    {
        privacy.set(this, {});

        const props = privacy.get(this);

        props.init = init;
    }

    setInit(tmp)
    {
        privacy.get(this).init = tmp;
    }

    getInit()
    {
        return privacy.get(this).init;
    }
}

module.exports = X;
```

Comment: this does not answer my question